# Ionic 4 2 menus on same page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm trying to add multiple menus to the same page in ionic however when I open up one of them I cant click on any of the links.

In my app component I have one of the menus in there and a separate component for the right menu.

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu menuId="mainMenu" side="start" contentId="mainMenu" swipe-gesture="false">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>Pages Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-menu-toggle auto-hide="false" *ngFor="let p of appPages">
          <ion-item [routerDirection]="'root'" [routerLink]="[p.url]">
            <ion-icon slot="start" [name]="p.icon"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>
              {{p.title}}
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <app-side-menu></app-side-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet id="mainMenu"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

This is my side-menu component

```
<ion-menu side="end" menuId="sideMenu" id="sideMenu" contentId="sideMenu" swipe-gesture="false">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="primary">
      <ion-title>Menu</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <ion-content>

    <div *ngFor="let p of menu">

      <ion-menu-toggle *ngIf="p.url">
        <ion-item [routerLink]="p.url" routerDirection="root" routerLinkActive="active">
          <ion-icon [name]="p.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
          <ion-label>
            {{ p.title }}
          </ion-label>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-menu-toggle>

      <ion-item button *ngIf="p.children?.length > 0" (click)="p.open = !p.open" [class.active-parent]="p.open" detail="false">
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="arrow-forward" *ngIf="!p.open">,/</ion-icon>
        <ion-icon slot="start" name="arrow-down" *ngIf="p.open">,/</ion-icon>
        <ion-label>{{ p.title }}</ion-label>
      </ion-item>

      <ion-list *ngIf="p.open">
        <ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-item class="sub-item"  *ngFor="let sub of p.children" [routerLink]="sub.url" routerDirection="root" routerLinkActive="active">
            <ion-icon [name]="sub.icon" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>
              {{ sub.title }}
            </ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
      </ion-list>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
</ion-menu>
```

and on my page that i want to display both menus this is the header

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button menu="mainMenu" autohide="false"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-buttons slot="end">
      <ion-menu-button menu="sideMenu" autohide="false"></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>

    <ion-title>
      Home
    </ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

everything shows correctly, the left menu works fine but when I open the right menu I can't click on anything or click away.

Comment: for triage of this can you try instead of packing your side menu inside a component just inline it straight away? i don’t recall exact issue but when i implemented double menu approach i had to have both components inlined inside app.component.html. please try and see if that way it works?

Comment: it needs to be in a component because it's a dynamic menu and uses a service.also if I inline it the same thing happens.

Comment: I see, yeah if overall it works I think it then only a matter of tuning the contentID in your case. Side Menu to work has to point at the appropriate router outlet. Not sure which router outlet your side menu currently points at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting side menu's contentId to the ID of the router outlet that has to render the route's content. In this case, I think you want to point to "mainMenu":

since:

```
<ion-router-outlet id="mainMenu"></ion-router-outlet>
```

you need to point your side menu at it:

```
<ion-menu side="end" menuId="sideMenu" id="sideMenu" contentId="mainMenu" swipe-gesture="false">
    ...
</ion-menu>
```